# Audio track in video file - C++

Tags: c++, video, audio, opencv

My application is transforming an [AVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave) video file into another AVI file. I use 
the [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) library. Unfortunately videos created with OpenCV have no sound as the library does not support audio.

Is there any easy way to copy the audio track from one video file to another? Maybe [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)?

My application is written in [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg). The easiest way would be to just use the command line tool to [extract](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#strip)/[reassemble](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#multiple). If you need your application to do it itself, looking into the sources for how they do it should help.

Alternatively, as you mention VC++, why not use [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783323(VS.85).aspx)? It should not be too difficult to sink the audio into a file for extraction and later sink the video/audio mix into a file for composition.

Comment: Thanks Peter,
Can you give some further hints how to do this with DirectShow?